# .NET 4.0 dll loading 4.5

Tags: .net

Can an assembly that has been targeted for 4.0 load an assembly that was targeted for 4.5?

For example, a project targeting 3.5 cannot load assemblies that were built against 4.0.

Comment: Why is this a comment and not an answer?

Answer (score 4):

<strike>4.5 is an inplace update to 4.0. So yes.</strike>

An assembly built against Fx 4.0 *can not* reference an assembly built against Fx 4.5.

However

An assembly built against Fx 4.5 *can* reference an assembly built against Fx 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea since your .NET4 app will also run on the machine with .NET4 only (without .NET4.5 installed). In this case, your app may run into issues because it may be trying to .NET4.5 functionality but .NET4.5 is not present on the machine. I strongly recommend building .NET4.5 app instead.

Comment: Payo didn't say that the machine would not have 4.5 installed.

Comment: Unless app will have to run on Win XP, which is supported only up to .NET 4.0, in this case you have to compile every assembly against Framework 4.0